# Read and add the first number of TXT file in java

Tags: java, filewriter

So How can I add +1 to the first number of the TXT file in java

for example my TXT is something like this

```
3
Text
Text
Text
```

It is easily to add more Text under, but I am not sure how to add 1 to 3 and so on

```
4
Text
Text
Text
Text
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file is small then read entire content, then edit, then overwrite it in write mode:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("e:\\data.txt"));
int num = Integer.parseInt(lines.get(0));
lines.set(0, Integer.toString(++num));
        
//by default opens file in overwrite mode
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("e:\\data.txt");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
for(String line : lines) {
    pw.println(line);
}
pw.close();
```

For large files you can use RandomeAccessFile class like this:
Have file contents:

```
0001
Text
Text
```

Then use following code:

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("e:\\data.txt", "rw");
int num = Integer.parseInt(raf.readLine());
num+=99;
raf.seek(0);
raf.writeBytes(String.format("%04d", num));
raf.close();
```

File will have following content:

```
0100
Text
Text
```